# Why my TensorFlow got warning for first run but then works?

Tags: tensorflow

Excuse for the stupid question from a newbie. I just got my TensorFlow, both GPU and CPU, installed on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on WSL2 with CUDA. My GPU is GeForce 940MX. When I try to test the TensorFlow installation, the first attempt got some warning as the message below. However, the exact same syntax following went through smoothly. I wonder what happened here? And is it using CPU or GPU actually?

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
2021-01-22 12:01:14.284464: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
>>> print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))
2021-01-22 12:01:20.034653: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-01-22 12:01:20.035316: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-11.2/lib64
2021-01-22 12:01:20.035400: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:326] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2021-01-22 12:01:20.035518: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (DESKTOP-3E6PSHT): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
2021-01-22 12:01:20.035984: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-01-22 12:01:20.036526: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
tf.Tensor(-872.4863, shape=(), dtype=float32)
>>> print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))
tf.Tensor(590.53516, shape=(), dtype=float32)
>>> print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))
tf.Tensor(294.59973, shape=(), dtype=float32)
>>> print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))
tf.Tensor(261.34412, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Anything helps!

Comment: No. TF is failed to initialize as it says in two warnings, may be, cuda is not installed properly or not right version required from tf. Nervertheless you can run on cpu with diminished performance. Check tf.test.is_gpu_available() for current gpu state.

Comment: There's nothing to worry about. They are just warnings and tell you that GPU couldn't be found so it won't be used. If you want to use GPU, use CUDA 11.0 instead of 11.2 version.Thanks!